# Nonblocking / busy waiting usage of Pyserial on Windows: How to monitor multiple serial ports in real time?

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, nonblocking, pyserial

I have a hardware test setup where up to 255 nodes send trace messages via USB connected virtual COM ports to my windows system. Actually I use a small Python script which runs a polling loop over all opened serial ports and does a readline with zero timeout. The read lines are printed with added COM port source and timestamp to the console. This works quite well an nearly in real time. But CPU usage is quite high as you can imagine. So I was looking for a way to monitor all the COM ports in parallel and real time without polling.

[PySerial doc](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html) *(look for `nonblocking()`)* says there is POSIX like select interface but only under UNIX OSes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you have separate threads for each com port, and each thread does a blocking read on its com port?   Then use a Queue to send back the timestamped data to the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at twisted, it might do the trick.  It has a Serialport monitor that is run by the reactor.  (twisted is async).

I have a small web server monitoring and communicating with a JeeNode (arduino clone) receiving data feed as well as sending data to remote wireless nodes.  You can see an early cut of this code here https://bitbucket.org/zutesmog/securitynode/src/93e29a7f3e26/SecurityConsole/secweb.py (its a bit hacky but you will get the idea.)

However this is not dealing with any where near the same volume of traffic or number of ports you are , but it isn't polling, so I am not sure if it will scale, but its certainly worth a try.